# I am working with Spring boot, Spring-data, ThymeLeaf. i am movie ticket is booking it is Should be able to tell the empty/Booked seats of a cinema

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

this is my column values. I am booking per day 20 tickets after 20 tickets booked it should able to tell ticket is full.  How can I achieve this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bookings")
public class BookEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String theatrename;
    private String moviename;
    private String bookdate;
    private String showtime;
    private int price;
    private int tickets;
    private int totalprice;
```

Comment: Spring boot has Min and Max annotations or you could put the logic in a setter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.